# Send Reset Link not working - Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement method to send an email for resetting password, however it is not working (I cannot reach the backend guy but he said its done on his part - maybe not but ok).

This is what I have so far - In my component i just take the email and pass into a function:

```
onSubmit() {
        const email = this.resetPasswordForm.value.email;

        if (this.resetPasswordForm.valid) {
            this.auth.sendResetLink(email);
        }

    }
```

then in my auth service I have this:

```
sendResetLink(email: string) {
    const body = {email: email};

      this._http.post('/auth/email/', '', body) // '' is for some query
          .map(res => {
              return {
                  email: res.email
              }
          })
          .subscribe(
              res => {
                  // console.log(res);
              },
              err => {
                  // this.error = true;
              })
  }
```

everything seems fine, it goes through and says that email is sent, but its not :) I inherited this project, I am trying to fix the broken stuff so no idea what is going on... Is this how it should be done for the most part or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: From what we can see, it seems that the frontend works correctly (even if you should subscribe to the observable inside the onSubmit method instead of sendResetLink to allow more control on your method usage).

Comment: from your question, i guess that the mail is generating from the back end api, you can check the api in postman if it really generating the mail.

Comment: You can easily test the backend part with **postman** if you haven't yet

Comment: @Polochon yeah, i just moved it in the service to try that as well (most of the stuff is done that way in the project, not great).. Thanks, ill try to check with postman or with the backend guy again.